# "Configuring a Device"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I came across a sentence in a product description:

> We recommend it is configured according to the Standard.

I would have written the sentence as

> We recommend configuring it according to the Standard.

Which version is right/better/wrong? Why?

Answer (score 4):

Your version is definitely better.

The first is definitely oddly worded and possibly grammatically incorrect. You recommend *something*.  Following "We recommend" with a statement about something's condition is odd, if not completely wrong.

I would either say it the way you said it or

> We recommend that it be configured according to the Standard

Comment: I took the liberty of changing *Second* to *the first* in your answer, as I'm quite sure you had meant to say that it was the first sentence that is odd.

Comment: @JasonBassford Yeah, that is what I meant. Thanks for fixing it

Answer (score -1):

They're both correct, and both are saying the same thing. However, the first is slightly more formal, so the choice of which is more appropriate depends on the register (tone) of the rest of the text. In a product description, the former seems to be the better choice.

Comment: I disagree. The first is very oddly worded and possibly wrong.

Comment: Very standard, actually. Having said that, Kevin's answer's suggestion of "We recommend that it be configured according to the Standard" is definitely an improvement.

Comment: It is not very standard.  Googles ngrams shows no hits whatsoever for We/I recommend it is.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=we+recommend+it+is%2CWe+recommend+that%2Cwe+recommend+that%2CI+recommend+that%2CI+recommend+it+is%2C+We+recommend+it+is&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWe%20recommend%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwe%20recommend%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20recommend%20that%3B%2Cc0